Find an example with L and M finite field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $L \cap M = \mathbb{Q}$ and $[LM:M] < [L: \mathbb{Q}]$
I am solving the following problem. Let $L$ and $M$ be finite field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Denote $LM$ the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $L$ and $M$. Assume $L \cap M = \mathbb{Q}$. Find an example such that $[LM:M] < [L: \mathbb{Q}]$. I have proved in another question that if $L$ is Galois over $K$, then $[LM:M] = [L: \mathbb{Q}]$. So I was trying possibilities where $L$ not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I could not find an example for which this inequality holds.

Does this answer your question? Is the proposition $[KL:L]=[K:F]$ iff $K\cap L=F$ for finite Galois extension still hold for separable extension? The counterexample there is with $F = \Bbb Q$, $L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$
